# Qt pointcloud slow performance in scene3d

Tags: c++, performance, qt, qml, glsl

I'm seeing major performance issues in a QML app I wrote to show a point cloud in a `Scene3d`. With 1000 points/sec it's alright, but at 10,000 it basically just halts my entire computer. The goal is to get up into the millions of points (which is what are old app, a Qt/VTK mixture could do before slowing down.)

I'm worried that I'm not offloading processing into another thread, or not rendering properly. ... This is my first Qt project and am new to all of this.

Basically I build a circular_buffer of points (each point is 32 bytes), which I copy into a `QByteArray` on a custom `QGeometry`, on an `Entity`. This entity has a material that runs a vertex and fragment shader.

Is there something I can do to increase the performance?

**material**:

```
import Qt3D.Core 2.0
import Qt3D.Render 2.0

Material {
    effect: Effect {
        techniques: Technique {
            renderPasses: RenderPass {
                shaderProgram: ShaderProgram {
                    vertexShaderCode: loadSource("qrc:/shaders/pointcloud.vert")
                    fragmentShaderCode: loadSource("qrc:/shaders/pointcloud.frag")
                }
                renderStates: [
                    PointSize { sizeMode: PointSize.Programmable } //supported since OpenGL 3.2
                ]
            }
            graphicsApiFilter {
                api: GraphicsApiFilter.OpenGL
                profile: GraphicsApiFilter.CoreProfile
                majorVersion: 4
                minorVersion: 3
            }
        }
    }
        // some parameters...
}
```

My shaders are pretty simple:

**vertex**:

```
#version 430

layout(location = 1) in vec3 vertexPosition;

out VertexBlock
{
    flat vec3 col;
    vec3 pos;
    vec3 normal;
} v_out;

uniform mat4 modelView;
uniform mat3 modelViewNormal;
uniform mat4 mvp;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewportMatrix;

uniform float pointSize;
uniform float maxDistance;

void main()
{
    vec3 vertexNormal = vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    v_out.normal = normalize(modelViewNormal * vertexNormal);
    v_out.pos    = vec3(modelView * vec4(vertexPosition, 1.0));

    float c      = (vertexPosition[0]*vertexPosition[0] + vertexPosition[1]*vertexPosition[1])*maxDistance;
    v_out.col    = vec3(c,c,0.5);

    gl_Position = mvp * vec4(vertexPosition, 1.0);
    gl_PointSize = viewportMatrix[1][1] * projectionMatrix[1][1] * pointSize / gl_Position.w;
}
```

**fragment**:

```
#version 430

in VertexBlock
{
    flat vec3 col;
    vec3 pos;
    vec3 normal;
} frag_in;

out vec4 colour;

void main()
{
    colour = vec4(frag_in.col, 1.0);
}
```

**Renderer**:

```
import Qt3D.Core 2.0
import Qt3D.Render 2.0

import "Cameras"

RenderSettings {
    id: root

    property CameraSet cameraSet: CameraSet {
        id: cameraSet
    }

    property real userViewWidth: 0.79
    property real topOrthoViewHeight: 0.79

    activeFrameGraph: Viewport {
        id: viewport
        normalizedRect: Qt.rect(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)

        RenderSurfaceSelector {
            ClearBuffers {
                buffers : ClearBuffers.ColorDepthBuffer
                clearColor: theme.cSceneClear

                NoDraw {}
            }

            Viewport {
                id: userViewport
                normalizedRect: Qt.rect(0, 0, userViewWidth, 1.0)

                CameraSelector {
                    id: userCameraSelectorViewport
                    camera: cameraSet.user.camera
                }
            }
            // Two other viewports...
        }
    }
}
```

**Entity**

```
Entity {
    property PointBuffer buffer: PointBuffer {
        id: pointBuffer
    }

    PointsMaterial {
        id: pointsMaterial
        dataBuffer: pointBuffer
    }

    Entity {
        id: particleRenderEntity
        property GeometryRenderer particlesRenderer: GeometryRenderer {
            instanceCount: buffer.count
            primitiveType: GeometryRenderer.Points
            geometry: PointGeometry { buffer: pointBuffer }
        }

        components: [
            particlesRenderer
            , pointsMaterial
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the problem, and it wasn't in the info I originally posted.

In the entity, I had `instanceCount: buffer.count`, but in my Geometry, I write the entire buffer in one step.  Therefore, I was effectively squaring the size of my buffer.

The solution was to set `instanceCount: 1`

I had puzzled on this line before, even removing it, but I suspect it defaulted to that value.. And I didn't understand the QML docs on what exactly this would do.

In any case, the real use of this is for geometries like `SphereGeometry`, which builds a buffer for each point.  So, given a point, it builds the vertices and indices to render a sphere around that point.  (I'm not sure why they don't do this in a Geometry Shader.)